# GPU allocation in Slurm: --gres vs --gpus-per-task, and mpirun vs srun

Tags: gpu, cluster-computing, nvidia, openmpi, slurm

There are two ways to allocate GPUs in Slurm: either the general `--gres=gpu:N` parameter, or the specific parameters like `--gpus-per-task=N`. There are also two ways to launch MPI tasks in a batch script: either using `srun`, or using the usual `mpirun` (when OpenMPI is compiled with Slurm support). I found some surprising differences in behaviour between these methods.

I'm submitting a batch job with `sbatch` where the basic script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=sim_1        # job name (default is the name of this file)
#SBATCH --output=log.%x.job_%j  # file name for stdout/stderr (%x will be replaced with the job name, %j with the jobid)
#SBATCH --time=1:00:00          # maximum wall time allocated for the job (D-H:MM:SS)
#SBATCH --partition=gpXY        # put the job into the gpu partition
#SBATCH --exclusive             # request exclusive allocation of resources
#SBATCH --mem=20G               # RAM per node
#SBATCH --threads-per-core=1    # do not use hyperthreads (i.e. CPUs = physical cores below)
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4       # number of CPUs per process

## nodes allocation
#SBATCH --nodes=2               # number of nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=2     # MPI processes per node

## GPU allocation - variant A
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:2            # number of GPUs per node (gres=gpu:N)

## GPU allocation - variant B
## #SBATCH --gpus-per-task=1       # number of GPUs per process
## #SBATCH --gpu-bind=single:1     # bind each process to its own GPU (single:<tasks_per_gpu>)

# start the job in the directory it was submitted from
cd "$SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR"

# program execution - variant 1
mpirun ./sim

# program execution - variant 2
#srun ./sim
```

The `#SBATCH` options in the first block are quite obvious and uninteresting. Next, the behaviour I'll describe is observable when the job runs on at least 2 nodes. I'm running 2 tasks per node since we have 2 GPUs per node.
Finally, there are two variants of GPU allocation (A and B) and two variants of program execution (1 and 2). Hence, 4 variants in total: A1, A2, B1, B2.

### Variant A1 (--gres=gpu:2, mpirun)

### Variant A2 (--gres=gpu:2, srun)

In both variants A1 and A2, the job executes correctly with optimal performance, we have the following output in the log:

```
Rank 0: rank on node is 0, using GPU id 0 of 2, CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1
Rank 1: rank on node is 1, using GPU id 1 of 2, CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1
Rank 2: rank on node is 0, using GPU id 0 of 2, CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1
Rank 3: rank on node is 1, using GPU id 1 of 2, CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1
```

### Variant B1 (--gpus-per-task=1, mpirun)

The job is not executed correctly, GPUs are not mapped correctly due to `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` on the second node:

```
Rank 0: rank on node is 0, using GPU id 0 of 2, CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1
Rank 1: rank on node is 1, using GPU id 1 of 2, CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1
Rank 2: rank on node is 0, using GPU id 0 of 1, CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
Rank 3: rank on node is 1, using GPU id 0 of 1, CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
```

Note that this variant behaves the same with and without `--gpu-bind=single:1`.

### Variant B2 (--gpus-per-task=1, --gpu-bind=single:1, srun)

GPUs are mapped correctly (now each process sees only one GPU because of `--gpu-bind=single:1`):

```
Rank 0: rank on node is 0, using GPU id 0 of 1, CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
Rank 1: rank on node is 1, using GPU id 0 of 1, CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1
Rank 2: rank on node is 0, using GPU id 0 of 1, CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
Rank 3: rank on node is 1, using GPU id 0 of 1, CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1
```

However, an MPI error appears when the ranks start to communicate (similar message is repeated once for each rank):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
The call to cuIpcOpenMemHandle failed. This is an unrecoverable error
and will cause the program to abort.
  Hostname:                         gp11
  cuIpcOpenMemHandle return value:  217
  address:                          0x7f40ee000000
Check the cuda.h file for what the return value means. A possible cause
for this is not enough free device memory.  Try to reduce the device
memory footprint of your application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Although it says "This is an unrecoverable error", the execution seems to proceed just fine, except the log is littered with messages like this (assuming one message per MPI communication call):

```
[gp11:122211] Failed to register remote memory, rc=-1
[gp11:122212] Failed to register remote memory, rc=-1
[gp12:62725] Failed to register remote memory, rc=-1
[gp12:62724] Failed to register remote memory, rc=-1
```

Clearly this is an OpenMPI error message. I found an [old thread](https://users.open-mpi.narkive.com/bt1qTy3M/ompi-users-cuipcopenmemhandle-failure-when-using-openmpi-1-8-5-with-cuda-7-0-and-multi-process) about this error, which suggested to use `--mca btl_smcuda_use_cuda_ipc 0` to disable CUDA IPC. However, since `srun` was used in this case to launch the program, I have no idea how to pass such parameters to OpenMPI.

Note that in this variant `--gpu-bind=single:1` affects only the visible GPUs (`CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`). But even without this option, each task is still able to select the right GPU and the errors still appear.

---

Any idea what is going on and how to address the errors in variants B1 and B2? Ideally we would like to use `--gpus-per-task` which is more flexible than `--gres=gpu:...` (it's one less parameter to change when we change `--ntasks-per-node`). Using `mpirun` vs `srun` does not matter to us.

We have Slurm 20.11.5.1, OpenMPI 4.0.5 (built with `--with-cuda` and `--with-slurm`) and CUDA 11.2.2. The operating system is Arch Linux. The network is 10G Ethernet (no InfiniBand or OmniPath). Let me know if I should include more info.

Answer (score 4):

I'm having a related issue. Running with

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=4
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
```

will result in the processes sharing a single GPU

```
"PROCID=2: GPU 0: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-715daa1d-db6f-9e69-ab48-190158bd5360)"
"PROCID=1: GPU 0: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-715daa1d-db6f-9e69-ab48-190158bd5360)"
"PROCID=0: GPU 0: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-715daa1d-db6f-9e69-ab48-190158bd5360)"
"PROCID=3: GPU 0: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-715daa1d-db6f-9e69-ab48-190158bd5360)"
```

This I suppose is correct.

Running with

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=4
#SBATCH --gpus-per-task=1
```

will result in only the last process receiving a GPU

```
"PROCID=2: No devices found."
"PROCID=3: No devices found."
"PROCID=0: No devices found."
"PROCID=1: GPU 0: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-02348a17-a825-300c-0336-48e33d0dadb2)"
```

Note different IDs in consecutive runs

```
"PROCID=2: No devices found."
"PROCID=1: No devices found."
"PROCID=3: No devices found."
"PROCID=0: GPU 0: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-715daa1d-db6f-9e69-ab48-190158bd5360)"
```

Running with

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=4
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:4
```

will result in each process having access to all 4 GPUs

```
"PROCID=3: GPU 0: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-715daa1d-db6f-9e69-ab48-190158bd5360) GPU 1: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-02348a17-a825-300c-0336-48e33d0dadb2) GPU 2: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-fbd9a227-e473-b993-215f-8f39b3574fd0) GPU 3: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-7843f55f-a15b-1d4c-229c-39b5c439bd5e)"
"PROCID=1: GPU 0: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-715daa1d-db6f-9e69-ab48-190158bd5360) GPU 1: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-02348a17-a825-300c-0336-48e33d0dadb2) GPU 2: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-fbd9a227-e473-b993-215f-8f39b3574fd0) GPU 3: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-7843f55f-a15b-1d4c-229c-39b5c439bd5e)"
"PROCID=2: GPU 0: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-715daa1d-db6f-9e69-ab48-190158bd5360) GPU 1: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-02348a17-a825-300c-0336-48e33d0dadb2) GPU 2: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-fbd9a227-e473-b993-215f-8f39b3574fd0) GPU 3: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-7843f55f-a15b-1d4c-229c-39b5c439bd5e)"
"PROCID=0: GPU 0: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-715daa1d-db6f-9e69-ab48-190158bd5360) GPU 1: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-02348a17-a825-300c-0336-48e33d0dadb2) GPU 2: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-fbd9a227-e473-b993-215f-8f39b3574fd0) GPU 3: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-7843f55f-a15b-1d4c-229c-39b5c439bd5e)"
```

Running with

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=4
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:4
#SBATCH --gpu-bind=single:1
```

will again result in only the last process receiving a GPU

```
"PROCID=1: No devices found."
"PROCID=0: No devices found."
"PROCID=3: No devices found."
"PROCID=2: GPU 0: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB (UUID: GPU-fbd9a227-e473-b993-215f-8f39b3574fd0)"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30980568)

Comment: I understand, but this was not intended as an answer. I posted the same issue, but with further explanations in hope that someone will have the answer based on the combined information. I too am looking for the answer.

Comment: the test results are helpful for me. Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted. You added insight to the thread, which to me and many others was more than enough. Thank you for your time to answer this thread and contributing to it.

Answer (score 4):

Just hit this (or at least a similar) issue myself. The problem is that using the Slurm launcher (`srun`) with GPU binding (either explicitly via using `--gpu-bind`, or implicitly via `--gpus-per-task`) will prevent CUDA IPC from working (which is the main mechanism MPI libraries use for direct GPU-GPU communication).

Note that `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` can be misleading: GPU assignment may also be controlled using cgroups (check `/etc/slurm/cgroup.conf` for a `ConstrainDevices` entry). The best way to check which devices are used is to call `nvidia-smi -L` which will print the device UUIDs.

So your options are

1. Use a different launcher which doesn't do binding (`mpiexec` or `mpirun`: note that in some cases this may just be a wrapper around `srun`)
2. Disable binding (`srun --gpu-bind=none`), and allocate your devices manually.

See https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/11949#issuecomment-1737712291 for more information.

> Clearly this is an OpenMPI error message. I found an old thread about this error, which suggested to use `--mca btl_smcuda_use_cuda_ipc 0` to disable CUDA IPC. However, since srun was used in this case to launch the program, I have no idea how to pass such parameters to OpenMPI.

You may not want this, as it will fall back to copying via the host, but you can pass mca options via environment variables, i.e.

```
export OMPI_MCA_btl_smcuda_use_cuda_ipc=0
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, FWIW - variant B1 won't work because `mpirun` uses `srun` under the covers only to launch its daemons. There is only one daemon/node, and thus `srun` is only assigning one GPU to that task (the daemon). The daemon then fork/exec's the application procs, which inherit that GPU assignment envar.

Variant A1 only works because you asked for two GPUs/task, and you happen to run two application procs on each node. If you had run a 3rd proc, or had asked for only one GPU/task, it would have failed - for the same reason as was given above.

Comment: Thanks, this basically explains why using `mpirun` directly does not work in multi-node cases. Do you have some insight for why the variant B2 does not work?

Comment: Long explanation here: https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/11949